# training model in english, but evaluating in another language for speech diarization task?

Tags: speech-recognition, kaldi

For speech diarization task, can i just train my model on english-based dataset (utterances of single words), but evaluate in my language?
Or this does not make sense, and the model will show poor results?

I need to implement a rather simple model, but there is no dataset in my language.

Answer (score 0):

Which language?
If the language is "close" ( linguistic speaking) to English ,  than you might get pretty reasonable results  .. 
I would suggest to look for data-sets in the closest popular language

Comment: there is no dataset in Russian ?  I thought you are talking about some minor languege with less than a milion speakers ,  just google "russian speech corpora"

Comment: Also , Russian is far from English , but not as far as the Asian language for example.